# Resized menu on bootstrap 3 slide from left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

It is possible to modify bootstrap js in order to slide that menu from left to right instead of from top to bottom when browser is re sized in a small window. 
Does anyone tried this ?

**[Here is a small example](http://jsfiddle.net/2R2WS/1/)** from left to right slide **but I need to modify this inside bootstrap.js**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#slideleft button').click(function() {
        var $lefty = $(this).next();
          console.log( parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) );
        $lefty.animate({
          left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ?
            -$lefty.outerWidth() :
            0
        });
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For that I wouldn't use navbar. And I don't think that modifying bootstrap.js is a good idea.
Have you seen this bootstrap example? http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/